# How to survive for a longer period of time?

Tags: arma-2

In Armed Assault 2 (aka ArmA 2), I try to go slow and shoot enemies, but I always die soon. I play on scenarios (against bots) to get better, but I still get defeated.

Does anyone here have any methods that they used to become a better played at ArmA 2? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AI in Arma 2 is able to see through foliage, unfortunately. This means, unless you have terrain (and the setting controlling tree detail, which I've forgotten the name of), you will most likely get shot at by bots seeing you through brush and grass. I believe there is a mod out that makes the AI more realistic, with vision obscured by foliage and not being able to see behind them without turning around etc.

If you're reluctant to modding the game (a rather painless process, considering how mod-friendly it is), you should at all times utilize your squad mates to their fullest extent. Put them in Danger mode (`7 "Combat Mode", 4 "Danger"` in the squad commands), to make them increase their chance of survival drastically by taking cover and covering each other as they advance. Your squad mates are just as cheap at seeing the enemy as the enemy AI is, which means they will see the enemy through bushes and grass as well.

Another thing to note would be to use the `1, 7 Find Cover` to make them seek out cover instead of just lying down on the ground or crouching. Be aware that their choice of cover may be pathetically poor, so some micromanagement wherein you individually order them to move to different cover location might be necessary.

To sum it up: Arma 2 is about the survival of your squad as a whole, instead of their individual efforts. If you want to survive in Arma 2, take cover, and yell at your squad mates.

Here's a neat guide into how to effectively manage your squad mid-battle: http://forums.bistudio.com/showthread.php?81123-GUIDE-AI-Squad-Command